# Why no stacktrace in logs on workers for "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark job which fails with GC\Heap space error. When I inspect the terminal I can see the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.compile(CodeGenerator.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchange.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:112)
    at     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:703)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:628)
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:514)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:784)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:3073)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$4900(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitLocalVariableDeclarationStatement(UnitCompiler.java:2958)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitLocalVariableDeclarationStatement(UnitCompiler.java:2926)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$LocalVariableDeclarationStatement.accept(Java.java:2974)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:2925)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:3033)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$4400(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitSwitchStatement(UnitCompiler.java:2950)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitSwitchStatement(UnitCompiler.java:2926)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$SwitchStatement.accept(Java.java:2866)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:2925)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:2982)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$3800(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitBlock(UnitCompiler.java:2944)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitBlock(UnitCompiler.java:2926)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$Block.accept(Java.java:2471)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:2925)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:2999)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$4000(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitForStatement(UnitCompiler.java:2946)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitForStatement(UnitCompiler.java:2926)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$ForStatement.accept(Java.java:2660)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:2925)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:2982)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$3800(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitBlock(UnitCompiler.java:2944)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$8.visitBlock(UnitCompiler.java:2926)
```

The problem is that the stacktrace doesn't appear on any of the workers logs (stdout and stderr) which I inspect using the webUI or directly the files on disk.

I do have a failed executor on the application which simply shows (stdout):

```
17:12:17,008 ERROR [TransportResponseHandler] Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from /<IP1>:35482 is closed
17:12:17,010 ERROR [CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend] Executor self-exiting due to : Driver <IP1>:35482 disassociated! Shutting down.
```

The stderr file is empty.

This is a big issue for me since I don't always see the entire log/stacktrace in the console and I look for something mode reliable/persistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.codehaus.janino` package is used for whole-stage Java code generation (see the line with `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute` in the stacktrace) that happens on the driver as part of query optimization (and before RDD is ready for execution).

> The problem is that the stacktrace doesn't appear on any of the workers logs (stdout and stderr) which I inspect using the webUI or directly the files on disk.

There should be no stacktrace in any of the workers logs as nothing has been submitted for execution on executors (and hence on workers) yet. It has failed before executors got it to execute.

Comment: is it possible to get Java heap space error in the code generation phase?

Comment: What exactly do you expect? What more would tell you that the driver's JVM is short of memory?

Comment: I run the driver with 4gb of memory, I am just asking if it is possible that this is filled with code?

Comment: Ah, you wanna see the code that fails compilation? Use `q.queryExecution.debug.codegen` where `q` is the query you wanna explore. You should not however as it's very internal. You may have ran into an issue in Spark. What's the version of Spark? Can you check out the latest 2.2.1?

Comment: I ran it on 2.1.0, changing the version will not be trivial.. I will inspect the debug options now

Comment: so I started checking, first, the debug.codegen doesnt work in Java, it translates to debug$ on which I couldn't run codegen. But I did run a smaller local example of my code which uses functions.window and it does create A LOT OF CODE. So I guess it does fail on the "compilation" and the HashMap is the variables HashMap (as presented above)

Comment: _"debug.codegen doesnt work in Java"_ you'd have to translate it to Java (and **does** work in Scala). Instead of dealing with this low-level internal OOME error, I'd review your query and the plan. That's going to be much easier. Thanks for accepting my answer!